# How do I insert attributes into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Each element in `$(some_selector)` has attribute `my_attr` (which is a number).

I would like insert all these attributes to array.

What would be the easiest way to do this using jQuery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this:

```
var arr = $("some_selector").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("my_attr");
          }).get();
```

Or as a number, parse along the way:

```
var arr = $("some_selector").map(function() {
            return parseInt($(this).attr("my_attr"), 10);
          }).get();
```

Either of these return a JavaScript Array.

Comment: Nick, in the second version: if map's function returns the number itself, why actually get() is needed ?

Comment: @Misha - `.get()` is calling `.toArray()` under the covers, it is just getting a clean array with no other jQuery properties left over :)